# get root node in Django model with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to get the root node of the tree in the model below:

```
# models.py

class Note(models.Model):
    note_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_note = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                                    null=True, related_name='subnotes')
```

```
Note_1
  Note_2
    Note_3
      Note_4
```

So if select e.g. Note 3, I would like to get Note 1
like this:

```
n3 = Note.objects.get(pk=3)
n3.get_root()
```

result should be:

```
<QuerySet [<Note: Note_1>]>
```

Code below returns all parent nodes of a given node.

I need only root (highest)

```
# models.py
...
    def get_parents(self):
            if self.parent_note is None:
                return Note.objects.none()
            return Note.objects.filter(pk=self.parent_note.pk) | 
                                       self.parent_note.get_parents()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the root node with:

```
def get_root(self):
    note = self
    while note.parent_note_id is not None:
        note = note.parent_note
    return note
```

Here we thus walk up the hierarchy until we find the `Note` with no parent. In that case we return that `Note`. An item can be root itself, so in that case it will return itself.

This is however not very "cheap", since it takes a linear amount of queries with the "depth" of the tree. You might want to take a look at [**`django-mptt`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) to implement tree-like structures more effectively.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me right now, but I will think about django-mptt for the future use